# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,) numpy related

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, machine-learning-model

I am trying to predict the pretrained model of keras Machine translation

but i get the error and i could not solve or find suitable answer

and it seems everyone gets this error

**code**

```
model = load_model('model.h5')
single_x_test = ['how are you']
model.predict(np.array(single_x_test, ndmin=0))
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected embedding_1_input to
>   have shape (4,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: Welcome to DS StackExchange. Could you please be more specific? We have no information about the data and the code used, as of now it's very hard to understand the problem.

Comment: the data is english and french sentences and the main model is translating as a batch which means test.txt file of sentences and generate the second file which is test_result.txt but i want make a prediction with only one input senteces

Answer (score 1):

The model excepts the input to be a 1D array with 4 items. The current input `single_x_test` is a Python list with 1 item. The model implicitly converts the Python list to a 1D array but it still only has 1 item.

The model needs to be introspected to see what 4 items it expects as inputs. Typically items are separate channels of information.

Comment: hi sorry i upload the model summarry will you be able to figure how to do it

Comment: model = load_model('model.h5')
single_x_test = [['how are you'],['hi']]
model.predict(np.array(single_x_test, ndmin=0))                                                                                      when i made 2 items still i get the same problem